# hibernate configuration in jboss 4.0.5

Tags: hibernate, jboss-4.0.x

i am trying to create a hibernate project with jdeveloper postgres 9.3 and jboss 4.0.5.
while i am able to connect to the database by jdeveloper conection when i invoke a simple servlet i get

`org.hibernate.HibernateException: hibernate.cfg.xml not found
        at org.hibernate.util.ConfigHelper.getResourceAsStream(ConfigHelper.java:147)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.getConfigurationInputStream(Configuration.java:1329)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1351)
        at testingmodel2.Example1Servlet.$init$(Example1Servlet.java:18)
        at testingmodel2.Example1Servlet.<init>(Example1Servlet.java:17)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:494)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:350)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:303)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1055)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:757)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:130)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:178)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:175)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:74)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:126)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:105)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.tc5.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:156)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:148)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:869)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11BaseProtocol.java:664)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint.processSocket(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:527)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.MasterSlaveWorkerThread.run(MasterSlaveWorkerThread.java:112)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:595)`

my hibernate.cfg.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1253" ?>

<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <!--<property name="hibernate.connection.datasource">
             jdbc/DBConnection3DS
        </property>
        <property name="show_sql">
             false
        </property>
        <property name="query.factory_class">
         org.hibernate.hql.classic.ClassicQueryTranslatorFactory
        </property>-->

        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">postgres</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">seaco712</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/dvdrentals</property>



        <property name="connection_pool_size">1</property>

        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>

        <property name="show_sql">true</property>





        <mapping resource="Employee.hbm.xml"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

and the web.xml is

`<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'windows-1253'?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd" version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee">
    <description>Empty web.xml file for Web Application</description>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Servlet1</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>testingmodel2.Servlet1</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Servlet2</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>testingmodel2.Servlet2</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>config</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/struts-config.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Example1Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>testingmodel2.Example1Servlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Servlet1</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/servlet1</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Servlet2</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/servlet2</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Example1Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/example1servlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>35</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>html</extension>
        <mime-type>text/html</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>txt</extension>
        <mime-type>text/plain</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <!--<resource-ref>
        <res-ref-name>jdbc/DBConnection3DS</res-ref-name>
        <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
        <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    </resource-ref>-->
</web-app>`

and the servlet code is

```
    package testingmodel2;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

import java.util.Iterator;

import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class Example1Servlet extends HttpServlet {
    SessionFactory sessionFactory =
         new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();

    public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
        super.init(config);
    }

    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request,
                                  HttpServletResponse response)
      throws ServletException, IOException {
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();

        Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
        Query query = session.createQuery("from Employee");
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("");
        out.println("");       
        out.println("");       
        out.println("");       
        out.println("");       
        out.println("");       
        out.println("<table>");
        out.println("<tr><th>ID</th><th>First Name</th>" +
                    "<TH>Last Name</th></tr>");
        for (Iterator it = query.iterate(); it.hasNext();) {
            Employee e = (Employee)it.next();
            out.println("<tr><td>" + e.getEmployeeID() +
                        "</td><td>" + e.getFirstName() +
                        "</td><td>" + e.getLastName() +
                        "</td></tr>");
        }
        tx.commit();
        session.close();

        out.println("</table>");
        out.close();
    }

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
                      HttpServletResponse response)
      throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
                       HttpServletResponse response)
      throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }
}
```

please help thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error message says it all: it can't find the hibernate.cfg.xml on the location you specified. Try setting it to the correct path in your jar/war/ear-file.

Comment: it seems that when open the generated ear/war file there is no hibernate.cfg.xml file .I am using jdeveloper to generate the ear file

Comment: Is the hibernate.cfg.xml located in a directory that is on the build path for the ear-file in jdeveloper?

Comment: Ok that was it ,i manualy moved the file to the WEB-INF !! Thanks a lot .